# Oracle SOA command line Ant build

Tags: ant, oracle11g, jdeveloper, oracle-soa

I'm having some trouble freeing component builds from JDeveloper Studio...

I have a reference to aia.jar set up in JDeveloper, which I can't seem to specify correctly on the Ant command line.

Here's my command line:

```
ant -f c:\...\jdeveloper\bin\ant-sca-package.xml 
    -D"compositeDir=c:/.../ProcessImpl" 
    -D"compositeName=ProcessImpl" 
    -D"revision=1.0" 
    -D"scac.application.home=c:/.../.adf"
```

Everything seems to go well at first, until it fails with: `package oracle.apps.aia.core.eh.logging does not exist`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution, for the sake of anyone that has the same issue in future...

My `aia.jar` lived in `jdeveloper/lib` ...

I had tried the `CLASS_PATH` environment variable, the `-lib <path>` option on the `ant` command line, and even adding to the `classpath` property in `ant-sca-compile.xml` - none of which made any difference.

The `aia.jar` file apparently **HAS** to exist in the `SCA-INF/lib` subdirectory of the project being built. In the end I created a wrapper `build.xml` file that copies the required dependency to this location and then calls out to `ant-sca-package.xml`...

```
<target name="build">
   <echo>Copy AIA.jar</echo>
   <mkdir dir="${sca-inf.dir}/lib" />
   <copy file="${aia.file}" todir="${sca-inf.dir}/lib"/>
   <echo>Create Package</echo>
   <ant antfile="${script.home}/ant-sca-package.xml" inheritAll="false" target="package">
      <property name="compositeDir" value="${path}/${name}"/>
      <property name="compositeName" value="${name}"/>
      <property name="revision" value="${rev}"/>
      <property name="sca.application.home" value="${adf.dir}"/>
      <property name="scac.application.home" value="${adf.dir}"/>
   </ant> 
</target>
```